# Не запускается таймер в Thread

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Есть код таймера который должен быть запущен в отдельном потоке при клике мышью.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread tmr = new Thread(TimerStart);
        tmr.Start();
    }
    private void TimerStart() 
    {
        date = DateTime.Now;
        timer1.Interval = 10;
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(TicTimer);
        timer1.Start();
    }
    private void TicTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        long tic = DateTime.Now.Ticks - date.Ticks;
        DateTime stopwath = new DateTime();
        stopwath = stopwath.AddTicks(tic);
        label1.Text = string.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss:ff}", stopwath);

    }
```

Однако ничего не происходит. Если же я просто вызову метод:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       TimerStart();
    }
```

работает без вопросов. В чем тут проблема?

Comment: могу ошибаться но мне кажется что он таки запускается, но label1.Text = string.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss:ff}", stopwath); ета вот штука дает ошибку,
там через инвоук както надо апдейтить тот же лейбл, погуглите

Comment: Судя по сигнатуре, это `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. Его событие запускается в гуевом потоке. Я думаю, вам нужен таймер, событие которого работает в отдельном потоке. Возьмите `System.Threading.Timer`. Но не запускайте его самого в отдельном потоке! И, да, при этом нужно будет использовать `Invoke` для обращения к контролам.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov  это опечатка `гуевом` ?

Comment: Это от английской аббревиатуры GUI - graphical user interface - графический интерфейс пользователя. По-нашему будет "гуй" - все так говорят :).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov про`Invoke` не понял.  Нужно в эту строку добавить - `label1.Text = string.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss:ff}", stopwath);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал Вам использовать таймер `System.Timers.Timer` и использовать его событие `Timer.Elapsed`. Преимущества данного подхода очевидны: метод, подписанный на это событие выполняется в свободном потоке из пула потоков `ThreadPool`, таким образом ваш основной UI-поток не блокируется на время выполнения трудоемкой операции. Если метод, подписанный на событие `Elapsed` должен что-либо изменять на форме, то можете воспользоваться `Invoke` и `MethodInvoker` для проброса через контекст синхронизации необходимой информации в UI-поток формы.

```
    private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
                {
                    timer.Stop();

                    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(MethodForInvoke));

                    timer.Interval = 5000;
                    timer.Start();
                }
```

Метод запуска такого таймера в отдельном потоке выглядит так:

```
 public void Run()
        {
            timer.Interval = 5000;
            timer.Start();



            while (!stopFlag)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            timer.Stop();


        }
```

Если хотите остановить поток с таймером, просто отправьте `stopFlag=true`, где `stopFlag` - поле класса, в котором находится метод `Run()`.

Answer (score 0):

Простой метод `BeginInvoke(new Action(() => timerStart.Enabled = true));`